# Registry GUID for Adobe PDF Reader in IE11

Tags: pdf, plugins, registry, internet-explorer-11, guid

Now that IE11 has retired, everyone has to use Edge. We have some apps that still rely on IE11 and were working in Edge under Windows 10 with IE11 compatibility mode enabled. However, since moving some computers to Windows 11, one app in particular has had issues opening PDFs. We believe it's because the Adobe PDF reader plugin for IE11 has not been installed on the Windows 11 computers. I know how to deploy IE11 plugins via group policy, but I can't find the registry GUID for this particular plugin. Does anyone know what it is please?